# Python: Split domain name from host name

Tags: python

I have a list of host names as such:

```
testhost.my.domain.net
host2.domain.net
host3.domain.name.org
```

basically there can be either 2 or 3 parts in the domain name.

I need to store the host name (testhost, host2, host3) separate from the domain name (my.domain.net, domain.net, and domain.name.org) in a table which is why i am working on splitting the name.

Here is the code I have so far however it does not work because the length of the split can very.

```
hostname = "practice-host.my.link.com"
split = hostname.split(".")
hostname = split[0]
domain = split[1] + "." + split[2] + "." + split[3] 
print (hostname, domain)
```

I would like to do something like this,

```
for i = 1, i < len(split):
domain += split[i] + "."
i += 1
```

but this of course won't work. Can someone offer a pythonic idea for how to achieve what i need?

Comment: Do you know about join, the inverse of split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
name = 'testhost.my.domain.net'
split = name.split('.')
```

You can get the host as the first element:

```
host = split[0]
```

The domain can be recombined with the inverse of `split`, which is `join`:

```
domain = '.'.join(split[1:])
```

Another way to do it is to only split off on the first occurrence of `.`:

```
host, domain = name.split('.', 1)
```

This version is arguably cleaner but less robust against missing name elements.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at your comment to lookup how join works. I had the host part but the domain part works using join. This is simple and clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) takes a second argument, `maxsplit`, which you could set to `1`:

```py
domains = [
    "testhost.my.domain.net",
    "host2.domain.net",
    "host3.domain.name.org"
]
split_domains = [d.split(".", 1) for d in domains]
```

Which will give you:

```
[
    ['testhost', 'my.domain.net'],
    ['host2', 'domain.net'],
    ['host3', 'domain.name.org']
]
```

Which is what I think you’re looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
hostname = "www.qq1.com"

domain_name = ".".join(hostname.rsplit(".",2)[-2:])
```

I guess is what you are asking for?